# How do I disable a LAN (Local Area Network) connection?

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, windows-firewall

I understand the command to show the Windows XP firewall status is:

```
netsh firewall show opmode
```

Which outputs:

[image]

To disable firewall type:

```
netsh firewall set opmode mode=disable profile=all
```

Which outputs:

[image]

But I cannot find the command to disable the Local Area Connection.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I cannot find the command to disable "Local Area Connection"

You need to use the `interface` option of `netsh`.

To disable:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=disable
```

To enable:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=enable
```

Notes:

- Replace `Local Area Connection` with the interface names of your adapter.
- Use `netsh interface show interface` to get the interface name.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)